# How to populate jtable with arraylist values?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I am doing a three-tiered project, this is the code from the presentation layer. I am not sure how to populate the jtable with arraylist values and i don't know much about tablemodels.

```
    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

    JButton btnLoadTable = new JButton("Load Table");
    btnLoadTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            Budget_Plan_Controller c = new Budget_Plan_Controller();
            ArrayList<Object> totable = c.retrievebudgetdata();


        }
    });
```

This is the code from the entity/data layer, this is to show that what is retrieved from the database is being stored into the arraylist.

```
public ArrayList<Object> viewbudgetplan(){

    ArrayList<Object> budgetdata = new ArrayList<Object>();

    try{

        Connection connection = sqliteconnection.dbConnector();
        String query = "select * from Budget_Plan";
        PreparedStatement  pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
        int id = rs.getInt(1);
        String groupid = rs.getString(2);
        String groupname = rs.getString(3);
        String grouptype = rs.getString(4);
        String budgetplanname = rs.getString(5);
        double budget = rs.getDouble(6);
        double materialcost = rs.getDouble(7);
        double transportcost = rs.getDouble(8);
        double logisticscost = rs.getDouble(9);
        double misccost = rs.getDouble(10);
        double totalcost = rs.getDouble(11);

        budgetdata.add(id);
        budgetdata.add(groupid);
        budgetdata.add(groupname);
        budgetdata.add(grouptype);
        budgetdata.add(budgetplanname);
        budgetdata.add(budget);
        budgetdata.add(materialcost);
        budgetdata.add(transportcost);
        budgetdata.add(logisticscost);
        budgetdata.add(misccost);
        budgetdata.add(totalcost);

    }
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
        connection.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return budgetdata;

}
```

this is the code from the business/control layer. This method just serves to retrieve the arraylist from the data layer and it is written in a way that the presentation layer can call this method to retrieve the database data.

```
  public ArrayList<Object> retrievebudgetdata(){
    Budget_Plan_Entity e = new Budget_Plan_Entity();
    ArrayList<Object> budgetdata = e.viewbudgetplan();

    return budgetdata;
}
```

[this is the content inside my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXHqn.png)

Comment: `i don't know much about tablemodels.` - see [Table Row Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step by step approach for creating a custom TableModel for a POJO.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest using some kind of POJO instead of just plain object some thing like this

```
public class BudgetTableRowData {

public final String groupid;
public final String groupname;
public final String grouptype;
public final String budgetplanname;
public final double budget;
public final double materialcost;
public final double transportcost;
public final double logisticscost;
public final double misccost;
public final double totalcost;

public BudgetTableRowData(String groupid, String groupname, String grouptype, String budgetplanname, double budget, double materialcost, double transportcost, double logisticscost, double misccost, double totalcost) {
    this.groupid = groupid;
    this.groupname = groupname;
    this.grouptype = grouptype;
    this.budgetplanname = budgetplanname;
    this.budget = budget;
    this.materialcost = materialcost;
    this.transportcost = transportcost;
    this.logisticscost = logisticscost;
    this.misccost = misccost;
    this.totalcost = totalcost;
}
```

}

Now you can load your database rows inside BudgetTableRowData objects from that point you can use reflection to present your data in table here is an example(this works so you can use it)

```
public class JtableTut {

public static void showTable(List<Object> data) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
        String[] columns = getColumns(data);
        Object[][] dataForTable = getTableData(data, columns);
        JTable table = new JTable(dataForTable, columns);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(900, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

private static Object[][] getTableData(List<Object> data, String[] columns) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    Object[][] dataForTable = new Object[data.size()][columns.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns.length; column++) {
            String value = data.get(i).getClass().getDeclaredField(columns[column]).get(data.get(i)).toString();
            dataForTable[i][column] = value;
        }
    }
    return dataForTable;
}

private static String[] getColumns(List<Object> data) {
    Field[] fields = data.get(0).getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    String[] columns = new String[fields.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        columns[i] = fields[i].getName();
    }
    return columns;
}

public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
    // This should be replaced with you logaci for bringing data from db
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 20;i++){
        data.add(getTableRowData());
    }
    showTable(data);
}

private static BudgetTableRowData getTableRowData() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return new BudgetTableRowData("dsadas", "group1", "creditor", "superBudget", rand.nextDouble(), rand.nextDouble(), rand.nextDouble(), rand.nextDouble(), rand.nextDouble(), rand.nextDouble());
}
```

}